# How do I get the currently authenticated user with Ember simple auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

If a user starts out in my app unauthenticated and then logs in, I can have my Rails back-end return the user data, and create a User model in my Ember app.

However, what if a user starts out in the app authenticated? How can I use `session` to fetch the user's details from Rails?

I'm using the ember-simple-auth-devise authenticator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use

```
this.get('session.user_email')
```

in my application route to find the authenticated user.

---

The better way to do it is to reopen the `session` object and add a property that references the authenticated user. See [this example from the guides](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html).