# How to get details about the current authenticated user in ember-simple-auth?

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I want to know how can I get the information about the current user in Ember. I'm using ember-simple-auth.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318610/how-do-i-get-the-currently-authenticated-user-with-ember-simple-auth) but couldn't access `this.get('session.user_email')`.

However, if I do the following in my `application.js` route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    console.log(this.get('session'));
  }
});
```

I get the following response:

[image]

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you injected the session object inside your route (or controller)

```
session: Ember.inject.service('session')
```

or short

```
session: Ember.inject.service()
```

Once you do this you should be able to use it inside template

```
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
```

or inside code:

```
this.get('session').invalidate();
```

Comment: i had to do `{{session.data.authenticated.uid}}` inside `{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}` to get the email id of the logged in user.